# PyCharm venv requirements, what the?

Tags: pycharm, python-venv

When I start a New Project in PyCharm I get an empty new project and a virtualenv created.

In this venv for some reason, I already have a lot of dependencies, I understand that some are needed by default, but before there were about 2-3, and now 44.

```
attrs==22.2.0
CacheControl==0.12.11
cachy==0.3.0
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
cleo==1.0.0a5
crashtest==0.3.1
cryptography==37.0.4
distlib==0.3.6
dulwich==0.20.50
filelock==3.9.0
html5lib==1.1
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==5.2.0
jaraco.classes==3.2.3
jeepney==0.8.0
jsonschema==4.17.3
keyring==23.13.1
lockfile==0.12.2
more-itertools==9.0.0
msgpack==1.0.4
packaging==22.0
pexpect==4.8.0
pipenv==2022.12.19
pkginfo==1.9.2
platformdirs==2.6.2
poetry==1.2.2
poetry-core==1.3.2
poetry-plugin-export==1.2.0
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pycparser==2.21
pylev==1.4.0
pyrsistent==0.19.3
requests==2.28.1
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
SecretStorage==3.3.3
shellingham==1.5.0
tomlkit==0.11.6
urllib3==1.26.13
virtualenv==20.17.1
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
webencodings==0.5.1
zipp==3.11.0
```

What happened and what am I doing wrong? PyCharm latest version, Linux Mint.

Comment: Do you choose to create the new venv from a clean Python base installation? It looks like you've already installed dependencies to the base interpreter you're creating the venv from.

Answer (score 0):

when creating a new project there is an option called "inherit global site packages" disable this and you will have a fresh project.

Comment: This option is disabled. But I create a new project again and get the same thing, 44 dependencies.